# What has more performance effect between invisibilityOfElementLocated() and invisibilityOf()

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, webdriverwait

In one of the learning tutorials, I learned that `invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.<locator>)` has more performance improvements than the `invisibilityOf(<web_element>)`.

Please can anyone explain why is this so?

Answer (score 2):

The code is basically the same. The only difference is that `invisibilityOfElementLocated()` takes a locator so it has to first locate the element (`driver.findElement(locator)`) before checking `.isDisplayed()`. `invisibilityOf()` takes an element so the `.findElement()` step is already done. So technically `invisibilityOfElementLocated()` would be faster because it's one step shorter. Having said that, 25ms or whatever to find an element on the page is going to be negligible compared to browsing to even a single page.

```
return !(driver.findElement(locator).isDisplayed());
```

[invisibilityOfElementLocated() source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c06370910c804e7de0cbdc3c1eae131bd634f55f/java/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java#L565)

vs

```
return isInvisible(element);
```

[invisibilityOf() source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c06370910c804e7de0cbdc3c1eae131bd634f55f/java/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java#L1372)

where `isInvisible()` is

```
return !element.isDisplayed();
```

[isInvisible() source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c06370910c804e7de0cbdc3c1eae131bd634f55f/java/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java#L1387)